# Меню из инфоблоков Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, меню

Здравствуйте. Перерыл много источников, но так и не нашел информации о том, как сделать меню в битриксе из НАЗВАНИЙ инфоблоков. Не из разделов одного инфоблока (эта тема уже перетерта на всех ресурсах по битриксу), а именно - один инфоблок - один пункт меню. Помогите с решением или дайте ссылку на документацию, где этот пример описан.

Answer (score 1):

Создаете (или используете имеющийся) тип меню. Для него создаете файл:
`.{MENU_TYPE}.menu_ext.php` например для типа "верхнее меню" с кодом `top` `.top.menu_ext.php`.

В этом файлике пишете что-то вроде:

```
    if (!CModule::IncludeModule('iblock')) {
        die('iblock module');
    }

    $iblocks = \CIBlock::GetList();
    while ($fields = $iblocks->GetNext()) {

        $aMenuLinksNew[] = array(
            $fields['NAME'],
            $fields['LIST_PAGE_URL'],
            '',
            '',
        );
    }
    $aMenuLinks = array_merge($aMenuLinksNew, $aMenuLinks);
```

Не забудьте при подключении компонента меню (`"bitrix:menu"`) добавить параметр `"USE_EXT" => "Y"`